# Print custom array in custom pattern

Tags: php, arrays, loops

If I have array looking like :

> Array ( [**date**_type] => Date [**date**_text] => 20/12/2012 [**place**_type] => Place [**place**_text] => NY )

How can I print result like :

```
<span>Date</span><div>20/12/2012</div>
<span>Place</span><div>NY</div>
so on.... (if more custom array)
```

I came to this step now

```
$custom_info = array (
  "date_type" => "Date",
  "date_text" => "20/12/2012",
  "place_type"=>"Place",
  "place_text" => "NY" 
) ;
$count = count($custom_info)/2;

for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++)
{

}
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Change the format of the array. While what you want is doable, the array structure makes it unnecessarily hard.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `for`.

Comment: Can you change the form of array like 'Date'=>'20/12/2012' like this. if it possible that is better solution

Comment: @Elby yes i/you can do :D , but i have to use 2 arrays for one type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your array always has the structure that you wrote, use this

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($custom_info as $k => $v) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0){
            echo "<span>".$v."</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<div>".$v."</div>";
        }

        $i++;
    }
```

tested

explanation:

according to your array structure, you should echo first element's value in span, and second element's value in div, and so on: `$i % 2 == 0` shows that when it is element number 0, 2, 4 and so on, print in span, and if 1, 3, 5 and so on, print in div. `a % b` gives the remainder when you divide `a` on `b`

```
$i = 0,  $i % 2 --> 0
$i = 1,  $i % 2 --> 1
$i = 2,  $i % 2 --> 0
$i = 3,  $i % 2 --> 1
$i = 4,  $i % 2 --> 0
```

Comment: can you expand about `$i % 2 == 0` ?

Comment: @l2aelba it's actually [well documented behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: :), but your array's structure always should be as you described, otherwise it will not work properly

Comment: Yes, my arrays gonna look like this pattern all the time

Comment: @Davo :  One thing, if i dont want to print `date_type` & `date_text` keys ??? (but its possible to some arrays one the top)

Comment: @Davo, forget it, i can use `strlen()` to print custom first array text :D

Comment: but it does not print keys, it prints just values of those keys

Answer (score 2):

Using [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php):

```
foreach( $custom_info as $k => $v){
    $parts = explode( '_', $k);
    if( count($parts) != 2){
       throw new Exception( 'Invalid format of key: ' . $k);
    }

    if( $parts[1] != 'text'){
       continue;
    }

    // Build label
    $key = $parts[0] . '_type';
    $label = '';
    if( isset( $custom_info[ $key])){
        $label = $custom_info[ $key];
    } else {
        $label = ucfirst( $parts[0]);
    }

    echo '<span>' . htmlspecialchars( $label) . '</span><div>' 
         . htmlspecialchars( $v) . '</div>';
}
```

Or you could replace `explode()` by function like this (which will support also `long_key_text`, using [`strrpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)):

```
function getParts( $key){
    $pos = strrpos( $key, '_');
    if( $pos === false){
        return false; // or array or so
    }

    return array(
        substr( $key, 0, $pos),
        sbustr( $key, $pos+1)
    );
}
```

---

Based on Elbys comment and your answer the simplest way how to do this would be:

```
$custom_info = array (
  "Date" => "20/12/2012",
  "Place" => "NY" 
) ;

foreach( $custom_info as $k => $v){
    echo '<span>' . htmlspecialchars( $k) . '</span><div>' 
         . htmlspecialchars( $v) . '</div>';
}
```